# Allow no whitespace in required form field

Tags: php, forms, validation, trim

I have a register form which allows users to create usernames and passwords. It requires the `username` field not be empty, but I need to require that it allow no whitespace at all.

I looked into `preg_match()` but I can't seem to get that to cooperate with my current code.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    /* Validate Username */
    if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
        $username_err = "Username Required";
    }
```

Comment: `else if(strrpos($_POST["username"], ' ') !== false){ $username_space_err = "Space found in username"; }`

Comment: Worked perfectly, had to play around with that for a second but that worked. So basically it's looking for the first occurrence of ' ' in the string $_POST["username"] and if it finds an occurrence it generates the error?

Comment: It finds the last occurence. You could use [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) instead to find the first occurence. But the result is exactly the same. So it doesn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use Regex for something so simple. With [strrpos()](http://php.net/strrpos) you can find the last occurence of a substring (space character) in a string (username).

If `strrpos` doesn't find a match, it will return false. So all you have to do is check if `strrpos` returns anything else but false:

```
if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
    $username_err = "Username Required";
} else if (strrpos($_POST["username"], ' ') !== false){
    $username_space_err = "Space found in username";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling any function on `$_POST()` I recommend calling `isset()` on the element to avoid receiving a Notice.

Using `isset()` will allow for the valid but unlikely username of `0`.

Calling `trim()` on a not-set element will cause a Notice.

I don't see any advantage in checking from the back of the string for spaces with `strrpos()` so I'll simply call `strpos()`.

If this is a simple pass/fail task (not trying to isolate the cause of the failure), use this:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9f7ede36055e2372cc5e472280f34b0ba599305))

```
$_POST['username']="0";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && strlen($_POST['username']) && strpos($_POST['username'],' ')===false){
    echo 'pass';
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Output:

```
pass
```

The beauty in this one-liner conditional, is that as soon as one of the conditions fails, the rest are ignored and the fail message will be displayed.

---

If you want to get a little crazy with micro-optimization, you can remove the `strlen()` call and just check for the existence of a first character (see if the first "offset" isset).

```
if(isset($_POST['username'][0]) && strpos($_POST['username'],' ')===false){
    echo 'pass';
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

And if we are putting tin-foil hats on, then a check to see that `$_POST['username']` is not an array should be included before `strpos()` is called (in any of the solutions on this page).

```
if(isset($_POST['username'][0]) && !is_array($_POST['username']) && strpos($_POST['username'],' ')===false){
```